# Spark 3.2 driver GC while reading JSON file, same works in spark 2.3

Tags: apache-spark

I am running a simple file load script in the below code:

```scala
val files = fs.globStatus(path).filter{_.isDirectory == false} // 50 file each of ~100 mb 
val fileMap = scala.collection.mutable.Map.empty[String, DataFrame] 
files.par.foreach {f =>
  val filename = f.getPath.getName.toString
  val df = spark.read.option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED").json(f.getPath.toString)
  fileMap.update(filename , df)
}
```

When run with 4Gb driver on spark 3.2 it throws error for reaching GC Overhead. On the other hand the same job when run in Spark 2.3 it completes without any error. In spark 2.3 the jvm dump shows around 2.3 GB usage while in Spark 3.2 it goes beyond 4 Gb and crashes.

All parameters remain same for both scenarios.

JSON file contains nested structure and have around ~800 cols.

In the above code I am not calling any action. map.update should store the reference of the dataframe. Why is driver consuming memory although no action is called and why the difference in behaviour in the two versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On taking the GC dump of the driver, I found that it is actually the fileMap & parallel iterable objects that are occupying more than 50G of memory space.
[image: JVM Object heatmap]

I fixed this issue by removing fileMap object and switch to JavaThreadpool for file.par as task support. [Details in my medium blog.](https://medium.com/dev-genius/debugging-a-memory-leak-in-spark-application-22140630877d)

Comment: Nice, but how were you able to get this picture of the GC dump in your cluster ?

Comment: This is using an in house tool. But eclipse MAT will also give similar viz.